# AngularJS with MVC and web api - ng-repeat issue

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am doing a tutorial that has a page that displays images. The images are flight seats. Either green for booked or red for available.

2 things:

1.) I don't understand how the 2 arrays are merged to be displayed in the html.
2.) The booked seats in green are not being set correctly. They are offset by 1.
    So if seat 3 is booked(not available) it should be green but seat 4 is 
    showing as green. How do I fix this?

Here a screen shot.
It shows a list of the booked seats with the seat number. They are all offset by 1 in the array of images.

[image]

Here is the booking.html that is displayed when a menu item is selected.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.10.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
        <link href = "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">           
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="routingApp" class="container">
        <div ng-controller="BookingController" align="center">        
            <br />
            <div>
               <b>UserName:</b>   <input type="text" ng-model="UserName" style="background-color:yellow" ng-blur="ValidateUser(UserName)" ng-click="RemoveTag()"/>
               <span ng-show="checkuser" style="color:green" > 
                 <br />                
                 <b>You have already booked your seat in SlotNo: {{SlotDetail}}</b>
               </span>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />

            <!-- Calls the function for displaying the seats - images. -->
            <!-- If hovered, calls a function for displaying a modal popup. Here, I can delete the booking. -->
            <!-- If clicked, calls a function for booking a seat (insert) for the given User. -->
            <div class = "panel-body" >
                <div ng-init="DisplayingImages()" >
                    <span ng-repeat="image in images track by $index">
                        <!-- If the seat is in the array of booked seats, then his/her details will be shown in the modal. -->
                        <span ng-if="(bookcollscope).indexOf($index) != -1" >
                            <img id="{{$index}}" ng-src="{{imageUrlBooked}}" ng-mouseover="showOptionDetails($index)"/>
                            {{$index+1}}
                        </span>

                        <!-- If the seat is NOT in the array of booked seats, then he/she can be booked a seat. -->
                        <span ng-if="(bookcollscope).indexOf($index) == -1">
                            <img id="{{$index}}" ng-src="{{imageUrlNotBooked}}" ng-click="BookMySeat(UserName,$index)" />
                            {{$index+1}}
                        </span>

                        <!-- CONCERN: what does this do? -->
                        <div ng-if="($index + 1) % 5 == 0">
                            <br></br>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <dotnetpiper-directive></dotnetpiper-directive>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the AngularJS function called from the booking.html.
It calls a stored procedure that returns booked seat numbers: 13, 26, 3, 9, 8, 14. These become positions in the array used in the html.

```js
        dataService.GetBookedSeatsForDisplayingImages(slotNum).success(function (result) {
            $scope.bookedSeatList = result;
          
            // Set the total seats red. totalseat is set to 30.
            var imageCollection = new Array(totalseat);
            $scope.images = imageCollection;

            $scope.imageUrlNotBooked = "../Images/RED.jpg";
            
            // Sets it to a list of the curently booked seats.
            $scope.bookcollscope = $scope.bookedSeatList;                        
            console.log($scope.bookcollscope);

            // There currently is 6 booked seats (13, 26, 3, 9, 8, 14).
            var imageCollection1 = new Array($scope.bookedSeatList);
            $scope.images1 = imageCollection1;

            $scope.imageUrlBooked = "../Images/GREEN.jpg";
        }).error(function (result) {
            $scope.error = true;
        });
    }
```

Comment: OK..as I looked at it again. I see part of my confusion. The 2 lines; var imageCollection1 = new Array($scope.bookedSeatList); and $scope.images1 = imageCollection1; really have no business being there and are not used. They in part were confusing me into thinking that $scope.images and $scope.images1 were being merged into 1 and used in the ng-repeat="image in images track by $index". I was thinking images reflected both of these.

Comment: I now understand that it is using the images and bookcollscope arrays only and the zero-based index. I tried your suggestion of adding in && $index != 0 to both inner spans. However, seats now start at 2 and showing only 29 (I loose the value of 30) and the numbering of the seats still does not reflect the correct seat. Number 4 is still green when instead 3 should be. This is due to {{$index + 1}}. So if I change that to {{$index}} the seats now start at 1, the seats number and colors are now reflected correctly, but I lose the 30th seat. It is labeled 1 thru 29.

Comment: It works now. I returned the spans to their original state - no '&& $index != 0'. Instead I added '$index + 1' in 4 places that just had '$index'. These do not include the 2 label areas that had '$index + 1' already. The result: the seat numbers start at 1, the seats correctly identify the booked seats(green) and I keep the 30th seat.

Comment: You'd probably do better by weaving your new finding(s) into an edit of your post. If nothing else, it's much easier to read in general but you can also block the code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

"1.) I don't understand how the 2 arrays are merged to be displayed in the html."

There are two arrays, `images` and `bookcollscope`. The `images` array contains a list of numbers from 0 to 29 I assume, each number representing a seat and the `bookcollscope` array has all the seat numbers which are already booked. Basically the two arrays are not really getting merged, instead with `ng-repeat` a seat is getting displayed for every element in the `images` array with this line of code: `<span ng-repeat="image in images track by $index">`
Now with the help of `bookcollscope` it is checked whether to print a red seat or a green seat. If the `$index` of `images` array exists in `bookcollscope` then it means that the seat is booked so the green seat is displayed otherwise a red seat is displayed.

"They are offset by 1. So if seat 3 is booked(not available) it should be green but seat 4 is showing as green. How do I fix this?"

The offset issue is happening because the first element in the `images` array is 0 I assume, to fix this change the condition to: `<span ng-if="(bookcollscope).indexOf($index) != -1 && $index != 0">` in both inner spans.

```
<!-- CONCERN: what does this do? -->
<div ng-if="($index + 1) % 5
    <br></br>
</div>
```

The condition above is to basically add line breaks if 5 seats are displayed.